# django admin cannot carryover object from one page to another admin page

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have two models(candidate and panelists) in my Django app, i have a link(for all candidate objects) in candidate admin page, when i click on it, it is redirecting to the panelists admin page, but I'm unable to see from which candidate object the panelists page has redirected. if I'm able to see from which candidate obj(or the candidate id) then I can filter panelists based on the candidate attributes.

```
class Candidate(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(auto_created=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class panelist(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=7,unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

here is the candidate admin

```
class CandidateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id','name''view_panelist'] 
    model = Candidate


    def view_panelist(self,obj):
        return format_html('<a href= "/admin/ttt/panelist/" class = "default"> View Panelist </a>')
```

Comment: hi. show your models, and your admin for these two models. It isn't quite clear from the question to me which is the 'parent'.

Comment: sorry, added admin and models

Answer (score 1):

Assuming...

1. you have a foreign key from panelist to Candidate
2. you have defined a filter for Candidate in the panelistAdmin

you can activate that filter by adding a direct lookup in the URL:

```py
def view_panelist(self,obj):
    base_url = reverse("admin:ttt_panelist_changelist")
    url = f"{base_url}?candidate__id__exact={obj.id}"
    return format_html('<a href="{}" class = "default">View Panelist</a>', url)
```

Comment: any other alternate method for non db fields